# Cassandra: how to create a trigger on a table whenever a row is INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: datetime, cassandra, triggers, insert, updates

In Cassandra database, I have a table with column: update_date. What i want is whenever i insert or update a record to the table, cassandra will have a trigger to update that column with current datetime or timestamp.

I know that in oracle we can create a trigger like that. But i am new to cassandra and want to know if we can do the same thing .

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra [supports triggers as well](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/triggers.html), but it's in general it's not recommended to use them until you know what you're doing - triggers in Cassandra aren't the general-purpose tool. You need to be very careful because it may hurt the performance. Plus you need to write it using Java or other JVM-based language.  There is not so much official documentation, only examples, like [this](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java).

But really, if you want to have a timestamp when row was modified, you can use the [`writetime` function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useWritetime.html) instead - it will return the timestamp with microsecond precision.  Although one potential drawback is that this value could be explicitly set when inserting/updating data.

Answer (score 0):

In case you weren't aware, all mutations in Cassandra (inserts, updates, deletes) are written with an accompanying timestamp so having to save it separately might not be necessary depending on what you need to do.

You can use the native CQL function `WRITETIME()` to get the time when data was written. It returns the date/time in microseconds. For example:

```
cqlsh:community> SELECT email, name, colour, WRITETIME(name) FROM users_by_email ;

 email                   | name  | colour | writetime(name)
-------------------------+-------+--------+------------------
 alice@getvaccinated.now | Alice |    red | 1629445088015677
```

In the example above, `1629445088015677` is equivalent to August 20, 2021 7:38:08.015 AM GMT. Cheers!